# read dataSet of picture with shape of [n, height, width, channels]

Tags: python, image, numpy, dataset, reshape

I have a base of 2100 pictures format `.tif` and I want to load it to generate a dataSet with shape `[2100,256,256,3]` but gives me `[2100,1]`

I want this shape `[n, height, width, channels]` to use it in **tesorflow train**

```
def datSetGenerator(path):
    classes = os.listdir(path)
    image_list = []
    for classe in classes:
        for filename in glob.glob(path+'/'+classe+'/*.tif'):
            image_list.append(cv2.imread(filename))
    return  np.array(image_list)
```

I tried `np.reshape` and `matrix.reshape` but always gives me an error

Comment: If you get a result of shape `(2100,)` instead of `(2100,256,256,3)`, it might fail to load images. Then your result will have the form `array([None, None, ..., None], dtype=object)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the right shape of **dataset**
If all the pictures with size `[256,256,3]` and one of them with different size, so the shape of dataset will be `[n,]`
so we need to resize all the pictures to the same size to get a shape of `[n, height, weight, channels]`

```
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
import cv2
def datSetGenerator(path):
    classes = os.listdir(path)
    image_list = []
    for classe in classes:
        for filename in glob.glob(path+'/'+classe+'/*.tif'):
            image_list.append(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(filename),(224, 224)))
    return np.array(image_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # for testing the generator
    path = "C:/Users/[USERNAME]/Desktop/UCMerced_LandUse/Images/"
    data = datSetGenerator(path)
    print("\n data shape :",data.shape)
```

this is the output

```
data shape : (2100, 224, 224, 3)
```